# How to pass XML with Hebew characters in it to VB6.0 code for database action?

Tags: xml, vb6

In my current flow, I pass a XML string to VB6.0 code. Sometimes it uses same string or sometimes it generates a DOM using that string.  Then that string or generated DOM is used to make INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE into database.
Now, when my XML contains Hebrew characters, VB6.0 accepts the string but when the value is accessed and stored in a variable for any further processing, due to its nature VB6.0 converts it into ANSI and same is stored into database.
How can I make VB6.0 to use Hebrew characters from input for database operation?

Comment: Please include relevant codes in your question.

Comment: VB can store Unicode. How do you store and show your text